# How to load a view + form in a modal window in Yii

Tags: php, yii

In Yii I have 2 models --> schedule and dossiers

**What I want to achieve:** In model schedule a view that shows a list of fiches. Each fiche has
a button that opens a modal window. The content of the modal window is a form to create a dossier + shows the 5 latest dossiers.

What I have so far:

viewSchedule.php

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('_fiches',array(
            'schedule'=>$model,
            'fiches'=>$fiches,
)); ?>
```

_fiches.php

```
<?php
 $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
                            'id'=>"dialogFiche",
                            // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
                            'options'=>array(
                                'title'=>'dossier',
                                'autoOpen'=>false,
                                'buttons' => array(
                                    //array('text'=>'Route','click'=> 'js:function(){'.$target.'}'),
                                    array('text'=>'Cancel','click'=> 'js:function(){$(this).dialog("close");}'),
                                ),
                                'height'=>400,
                                'width'=>650,
                                'show'=>'fade',
                                'hide'=>'fade',
                            ),
                      ));


                      $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
?>

<?php foreach($fiches as $fiche): ?>
    //fiche html ...
    <div class="editDossier">

                 <?php 

                     // the link that may open the dialog
                       echo CHtml::htmlButton("Edit dossier",
                            array(
                                'ajax'=>array(
                                    'url' => CController::createUrl('dossier/getDossierById'),   //only if you want an action here
                                    'type' => 'get',
                                    'data' =>  array(
                                        'id' => $fiche['id'],
                                        'isAjax' => 1,
                                    ),
                                    "success" => "function(data){
                                        $('#dialogFiche').html(data);
                                        $('#dialogFiche').dialog('open'); 
                                        return false;
                                    }", 
                                ),
                                'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-medium btn2',
                            ),
                            array('id' => 'get-dossier-'.uniqid())
                        );
                 ?>


    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

dossierController.php

```
public function actionGetDossierById($id){
        $dossiersById = dossier::model()->getDossiersById($id, 5);

        $fiche = Fiche::model()->findByPk($id);
        $dossier = $this->newDossier($fiche);

        $myHtml = $this->renderPartial(
                'viewDossierInModal',
                array(
                    'dossiers'=>$dossiersById,
                    'dossier'=>$dossier,
                ),
                true
        );
        echo $myHtml;
        Yii::app()->end();                                 
        return;
    }

protected function newDossier($fiche)
{
        $dossier = new Dossier;

        if(isset($_POST['Dossier']))
        {
            $dossier->attributes = $_POST['Dossier'];
            $dossier->fiche_Id = $fiche->id;

            if($dossier->save())
            {
                echo 'succes';    
            }else{ 
                echo 'failed';
            }
        }
        return $dossier;
}
```

dossierModal.php

```
public function getDossiersById($id, $limit = null){

        $crit = new CDbCriteria();
        $crit->condition = "fiche_Id = :ficheId";
        $crit->params = array("ficheId"=>$ficheid);
        if(isset($limit)){
            $crit->limit = $limit;
        }
        $crit->order = "datum DESC";
        return $this->findAll($crit);
    }
```

After I create a dossier in the modal, the page does a redirect and shows the form and latest 5 dossiers on a new blank page. How can I return to my viewSchedule.php and maybe open the modal window with the content updated?
Or is there another, easier or maybe already in Yii, solution?

Answer (score 0):

i hope i can help you,

The code that is making you the redirection is in the

```
actionGetDossierById


$myHtml = $this->renderPartial(
        'viewDossierInModal',
        array(
            'dossiers'=>$dossiersById,
            'dossier'=>$dossier,
        ),
        true
);
```

if you remove or modify your `$myHtml` you will be able to handle redirection.

Also check your   `newDossier()` function i think you miss an "s" in `success` so your ajax is not getting a success but a succes...

Regards